# Запретить создание и удаление страниц-записей второму администратору

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как можно ограничить роль второго администратора в админ-панели?
Допустим, на сайте зарегистрированы два администратора, второй нужен для тестирования и отладки сайта на wordpress.

Действия, которые нужно запретить для 2го администратора такие:

- добавление новых страниц-записей,
- удаление существующих страниц-записей,
- установка плагинов-тем, удаление плагинов-тем (но просмотр установленных плагинов-тем должно быть возможно для 2го админа).

Т.е. нужно удалить кнопку "Добавить новую" для записей и тем, или "Добавить новый" для плагинов и запретить удалять записи-плагины-темы.

Использовал такой код в небольшом плагине, но он не работает:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'adminka_install' );

function adminka_install() {

    //Удаление некоторых прав у пользователя user
    remove_cap_user();

}
function remove_cap_user() {
    $user_id = 3; // ID администратора, которго надо ограничить в правах
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $caps = array(
        'delete_published_pages',
        'delete_published_posts',
        'delete_posts',
        'delete_pages',
        'publish_posts',
        'upload_files',
        'install_plugins'
    );

    foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
        $user->remove_cap( $cap );
    }
}
```

P.S. дополню, что нужно оставить возможность просмотра всех страниц в админке для 2го администратора, но нужно запретить действие для бд: update, insert и delete, т.е. запретить изменение и удаление записей и плагинов ( ну и тем естественно ).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57818/discussion-on-question-by-word-------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте новую роль (например, "Ограниченный Админ") и задайте ей только те права, которые хотите выдать.
Новая роль создаётся функцией [add_role()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

**Upd.** вот пример создания новой роли на основе роли админа. Сразу оговорюсь, что право создания записей и кнопка "Добавить запись" выводится на основе анализа права пользователя редактировать записи (`edit_posts`), на основе этого же права определяется право пользователя видеть страницу `/wp-admin/edit.php`. То есть ограничить его в этом праве не получится. Выходом может служить ограничение права на публикацию записей (`publish_posts`), в таком случае все созданные им записи будут отправляться на утверждение и нигде на фронтэнде не появятся, что, как я понимаю, частично решает задачу.

```
function create_small_admin() {
    if (get_role('small_admin') == null) {
        $user = new WP_User(1); // получим экземпляр класса пользователя с правами админа (как правило это пользователь с id=1)
        $adm_caps = $user->get_role_caps(); // получим массив возможностей админа

        $caps = array(
            'edit_others_posts', // нельзя редактировать чужие записи
            'delete_others_posts', // нельзя удалять чужие записи
            'publish_posts', // как уже говорилось выше, право edit_posts отключает всё меню с записями, поэтому можно запретить пользователю публиковать созданные записи (они будут отправляться на утверждение)
            'upload_files',
            'install_plugins',
            'delete_plugins',
            'update_plugins',
            'edit_plugins'
        );
        foreach ($caps as $cap) {
            unset($adm_caps[$cap]); // удалим некоторые возможности
        }
        add_role('small_admin', 'Младший Администратор', $adm_caps); // создадим новую роль на основе роли админа, но с урезанными правами

        $user = new WP_User(3);
        $user->set_role('small_admin'); // установим новую роль для пользователя с id = 3 (то же самое можно и правильнее будет делать из админки)
    }
}
add_action('init', 'create_small_admin');
```

Как итог - невозможность пользователя с ролью `small_admin` редактировать чужие записи, устанавливать, обновлять, удалять и редактировать плагины, загружать файлы. Свою запись можно создать и отправить на утверждение, но не опубликовать.

Comment: Новую роль удобно создавать по причине того, что не придётся для каждого нового пользователя каждый раз удалять определённый список прав. Очевидных ошибок в вашем коде вроде бы нет, попробуйте отловить момент, на котором всё ломается. Выведите где-нибудь список всех прав пользователя с id=3, попробуйте выполнить функцию не в плагине и т. д.

Comment: убрав какую-то роль у администратора, некоторые страницы админ-панели могут вообще быть не доступны для данного админа. А нужно оставить все страница только для просмотра, но удалить все возможности по изменению-добавлению-удалению записей или плагинов.

Comment: Я вас поняла. Дело не в роли, а в праве на редактирование постов. Оно определяет показывать страницу записей или нет. Увы, по этой причине совсем убрать право на создание записей не получится. Дополнила ответ решением, которое может быть выходом из этой ситуации

Comment: благодарю за решение!

Comment: кстати подскажите пожалуйста, решит ли данную проблему удаление всех кнопок из админки, такие как "Добавить новую" на странице записей, или "Добавить новый" на странице плагинов? Допустим с помощью jquery.
Или это не решит проблему, тк можно в get-запросе подстроить любые ненужные данные даже с удалёнными кнопками?

Comment: всё зависит от хитрости вашего младшего админа :) ведь ничто не помешает ему руками вписать в адресную строку `/wp-admin/post-new.php`, хотя соблазна лезть куда не надо будет меньше, конечно

Comment: это понятно что не помешает. Даже наверно не опытный сможет закрыть страницу post-new.php с помощью exit() или подобной функции. Можно ли обойти и эту хитрость?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - прицепиться к событию создания поста и проверять роль пользователя, возвращая `false` при необходимости. Ну и анализировать `$current_screen` и сопоставлять с ролью текущего пользователя, если роль `small_admin` и текущий экран == создание нового поста, то редиректить обратно в список записей.